# ошибка invalid poiner operation при хоr шифровании Delphi

Tags: массивы, delphi

Возникла очень странная ошибка invalid pointer operation , еще страннее периодичность ее появления. Есть код :

```
for i := 0 to (fpos div length(longke)) do
  longkey := longkey + longke;

for i:= 0 to fpos do
  AByte[i]:= AByte[i] xor ord(longkey[i+1]);
```

заметил, что, если убрать цикл

```
for i := 0 to (fpos div length(longke)) do
  longkey := longkey + longke;
```

то ошибки нет, так же методом тыка понял, что если закоментить строку

```
AByte[i]:= AByte[i] xor ord(longkey[i+1]);
```

то ошибки тоже нет, значит дело явно с ней. Сама же ошибка возникает в конце программы и показывает

```
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.  // сюда
```

иногда ошибка сама уходит, я ничего не трогал, код не менял и вдруг ошибка  перестала появляться, но потом опять начала, что за магия ?

дополнение#1 :
понял, что если объявить массив статическим, то ошибки нет, вот код :

```
var
  f: file of byte;
  AByte: array of byte;
  bytee : byte;
  i,k,fpos,sc,vv,pol :integer;
  CodeText : longint;
  longke,longkey: AnsiString;
begin
  longke:='c28a50a73a5ccc2373c1015e41022df4';
  AssignFile(f, 'C:\45.docx');
  Filemode := 2;
  Reset(f);
  k := FileSize(f);
  fpos:=200;
  SetLength(AByte, fpos);
  for i := 0 to (fpos div length(longke)) do
    longkey := longkey + longke;

  seek(f,0);
  BlockRead(f, AByte[0], fpos);

  for i:= 0 to fpos do
    AByte[i]:= AByte[i] xor ord(longkey[i+1]);
  seek(f,0);
  BlockWrite(f, AByte[0], fpos);
end;
```

Comment: ну а если подумать - на последнем витке цикла куда будет указывать i+1? Да и не обязательно на последнем

Comment: не от этого ошибка, ибо я недавно эт добавил, было просто i , да и в longkey больше символов чем в fpos

Comment: что самое интересное, я вместо ord(longkey[i+1]); делал просто random(255) и все равно ошибка вылезала ((

Comment: тогда приводите весь код, относящийся к ошибке. Сейчас совершенно непонятно, что за переменные используются, как они заполняются. Особенно - longkey и AByte. Возможно, где-то еще вы портите память, тогда поможет FastMM

Comment: var
  f: file of byte;
  AByte: array of byte;
    i,k,fpos,sc,vv,pol :integer;
    longke,longkey: AnsiString;

границы массива 
SetLength(AByte, 200);

Comment: немного не так. Отредактируйте вопрос. И помимо объявления - покажите, где вы инициализируете переменные. В общем - нужен минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: о, благодаря вам понял в чем точно дело, дело в динамическом массиве, если его объявить статическим , то ошибки нет

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @Lolidze Не "ошибки нет", а "Вы ее не видите". Ошибка из-за нарушения границ массива. Детальнее можно сказать только увидев весь код. Включите в настройках компилятора опцию Range Check и посмотрите, что получится. Ну и про FastMM Вам уже говорили

Comment: @Lolidze объявление переменных где?

Comment: это весь код, добавил переменные. 
Включил опцию Range Check, если массив сделать статичным, то ошибок все так же нет

Comment: @Lolidze Это не весь код. При таком коде `length(longke)` будет равно нулю и `fpos div length(longke)` будет давать ошибку Division by zero

Comment: извините, забыл про longkey, добавил

Comment: Из того, что есть сейчас - ошибка в цикле по AByte. Цикл должен идти до fpos-1, иначе он пройдет 201 раз вместо 200. Ну и длина longkey явно недостаточна.

Comment: kami, почему ? массив же начинается с 0, а в longkey записано 224 символа (если fpos ==200)

Comment: а не, понял, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `SetLength(AByte, fpos);`

Устанавливает массив `AByte` размером `fpos` элементов. Индексация элементов от 0 до `fpos - 1`

> `for i:= 0 to fpos do
>    AByte[i]:= AByte[i] xor ord(longkey[i+1]);`

На последней итерации цикла идет обращение к элементу массива `AByte` с индексом `fpos`. Элемента с таким индексом не существует и мы затираем чужую память